# Show that $R/I\otimes_R I\cong R/I\oplus R/I$ and $\text{Frac } R\otimes_R I\cong \text{Frac } R$

Tags: modules, tensor-products, exact-sequence, free-modules

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[X,Y], I=(X,Y)$ and $K$ the fraction field of $R$, where we view $K$ as an $R$-module. Show that
$$ R/I\otimes_R I\cong R/I\oplus R/I\quad\text{and}\quad K\otimes_R I\cong K.$$
Conclude that $I$ is not a free $R$-module.

This is the third part of a past exam question I am working on at the moment, and I can't figure out how to show the first isomorphism. The second one seems straightforward since $\frac{p}{q}\otimes f=\frac{pf}{q}\otimes 1\in K\otimes_R I$. The first two parts of the question ask us to show that if $M$ is an $R$-module and
$$0\to N\to E\to N'\to 0 $$
is split short exact sequence of $R$-modules then
$$ 0\to M\otimes_R N\to M\otimes_R E\to M\otimes_R N'\to 0 $$
is a split short exact sequence. We then use this to conclude that $M\otimes_R(N\oplus N')\cong (M\otimes_R N)\oplus (M\otimes_R N')$. So I guess this needs to be used somewhere when showing that $I$ is not a free $R$-module, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: $R/I \simeq \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You might want to double check the calculation for showing $\operatorname{Frac}R\otimes I\cong \operatorname{Frac}R$.

Comment: @rogerl I can see that, but I'm not sure how it helps me to construct a map $\mathbb{C}\otimes (X,Y)\to \mathbb{C}^2$. Would it be something like $\lambda\otimes f(X,Y)\mapsto (f(\lambda, 0), f(0,\lambda))$?

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld I didn't want to write the full proof, but what I meant was to take a map $\varphi:K\times I\to K, (p/q,f)\mapsto pf/q$ and then show that it is the tensor product. Is this approach incorrect?

Comment: @14159: It's a start. I can't tell if it is correct unless you execute it. Here's a potentially different approach: $K\otimes I \to K\otimes R$ is injective (because $K\otimes -$ is localization with respect to a multiplicative set), but both terms are vector spaces over $K$. Deduce the dimension of $K\otimes I$.

Comment: @14159: For the first part: $R/I\otimes M \cong M/IM$, as $R/I$-modules. In this case, you can work directly with the $\mathbb C$-module $I/I^2$.

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld So $R/I\otimes I\cong I/I^2=(X,Y)/(X^2, XY, Y^2)$ and the isomorphism $I/I^2\to R/I\oplus R/I$ would be given by $aX+bY\mapsto (a,b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the computation of $R/I\otimes I$, use the fact that $-\otimes I$ is right exact, and apply that to the exact sequence $0\to I\to R \to R/I\to 0$. This implies $$R/I\otimes I\cong I/I^2$$
In the situation of the problem one notes that $I/I^2$ is a vector space over $R/I\cong \mathbb C$ and has basis $\overline X,\overline Y$. More generally, consider the situation where $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of a ring $A$ with residue field $k:=A/\mathfrak m$. Then, $A/\mathfrak m^2$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$, so that $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ can be computed after localizing $A$ with respect to the ideal $\mathfrak m$. Then, by Nakayama's lemma, we have $$\dim_kA/\mathfrak m\otimes_A\mathfrak m = \text{minimal number of generators of $\mathfrak mA_{\mathfrak m}$}$$
Anyway, we have that in the problem statement, $\dim_{\mathbb C}R/I\otimes I = 2$.

For the second isomorphism, consider an exact sequence $$0\to M'\to M \to M''\to 0$$ of $R$-modules. Suppose $\operatorname{ann}_RM''\ne 0$. Since every nonzero element of $R$ is invertible in $K$, we have $M''\otimes K\cong 0$. On the other hand, $-\otimes K$ is exact because it is the same as localizing with respect to the multiplicative set $R\setminus\{0\}$. Hence, we have an exact sequence $$0\to M'\otimes K\to M\otimes K\to 0$$
which is the same as saying $M'\otimes K\cong M\otimes K$. Apply this observation to the short exact sequence $$0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$$and you will get the desired isomorphism. The dimension of $M\otimes K$ is called the rank of $M$, for any $R$-module $M$, so the problem has you showing that $I$ is an $R$-module of rank $1$. Can you come up with an equation for the ranks of $M',M,M''$ in the above short exact sequence without making any assumptions on the annihilator of $M''$?

For the conclusion that $I$ is not free, note that if $F$ is a free $R$-module of rank $r$, then for any $R$-module $M$, we have
$$F\otimes M\cong M^r$$
by the earlier parts of the problem. In particular, $\dim_{\mathbb C}F\otimes R/I = \dim_{K}F\otimes K$. This shows that $I$ cannot be a free $R$-module.